# How can I find the projection of one polygon onto another?

Tags: algorithm, geometry

I have two 2D polygons. One of the polygons will be smaller or of the same same as the other. I was to project the smaller polygon onto the larger. I can do this by brute force. I would like to know if there is a way to compute it directly or at least efficiently.

To help explain what I mean, consider this simple case:

[image: simple case]

In this case, `b` is smaller than `a`. Both a & b have vertices at the red circles. I can compute that these two vertices are the closest between the two polygons. The projection vector between b & a can be determined by using these two vertices. With the projection vector, the two blue vertices on `a` can be determined. Once I have the two blue vertices, I have the information I need.

But, now consider the case:

[image: complex case]

Again, the two red vertices can assist in providing a projection vector, but the direction of the vector does not provide the ability to find the intersecting blue points.

I have to adjust the projection vector to something closer to the red arrow. Following this projection, `a` is viewed as smaller than `b`.

I can start with the original projection vector between the two red vertices, and brute force search vectors between it and -90degrees to +90degrees from it, but that takes a long time.

Is there a way to directly compute the projection and find the blue vertices?

Comment: [The projection is defined by parallel lines that enclose both objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FX1y.png). More than one projection is possible in both of your examples.

Comment: I believe there are an infinite number of  possible projections. I am not seeking a "best" or "optimal" projection - just something that is reasonable, like in the simple case above. How would I find those parallel lines?

Comment: The general idea is to find a line that touches both polygons, does not intersect with either polygon, and does not separate the polygons. [The red line is not a valid first line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tti28.png), since it separates the polygons. The second line is parallel to the first, touches the larger polygon, and encloses the smaller polygon.